# tensorflow training saving model

Tags: tensorflow

With the tensorflow example script train.py from the directory object_detection
it is possible to define how often the model should be saved during training.

How can the example be modified in order to save a model after some conditions
are met?

For example: loss values are during N training steps continually under the limit L.

Resource: [TensorFlow Models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/train.py).

Comment: Please post the link to the source you're referring to.

Comment: Hallo, the script train.py is from Tensorflow object detection repository  https://github.com/tensorflow/models   directory models-master/research/object_detection